# What is the explanation for the laughing ostrich meme in Family Guy?

Tags: reference, family-guy

In Family Guy, there is a recurrent meme of an ostrich who sarcastically laughs "ha hahhhh":

[image]

Is there an explanation or back story for this meme?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He first appears in the episode "Oceans Three and a Half" when Peter turns on *Three and a Half Men*, which begins with the line "*Three and a Half Men* was filmed in front of a live ostrich." After a lame joke, the ostrich is shown laughing as the lone audience member.

He appears in several later episodes, reprising his role as the ostrich laughing at a lame joke. In one episode he is identified as "Eddie" by other ostriches. That is the extent of his backstory.

Comment: Right, I remember that now.

Comment: For the reference, Eddie the Ostrich turning up outside the wrong house in Spooner Street.
https://youtu.be/dSjJzjkppew [Eddie](https://youtu.be/dSjJzjkppew)